# checking about moving an uninitialized variable and using a moved variable

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, warnings, move

After a debug session I realised that the next sample code compile with no warnings (g++-4.7.2 -Wextra and -Wall)

```
char *p;
char *q = std::move(p);
*p = 'p';
*q = 'q';
```

I'm a bit shocked, and I have three questions about it.

1- Am I missing something about move semantics and there is a reason for not issuing a warning in this situation, or is gcc's checking not good enough?

2- Should the next code throw a warning?

```
char c = 'c';
char *p = &c;
char *q = std::move(p);
*p = 'p';
```

As far I understand, after `std::move(p)` `p` can hold any value, therefore once `p` is moved is like an uninitialized variable.

3- Can other tools/compilers check these errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1- I'm missing something about move semantics and there is a reason for no throw a warning in this situation, or gcc checking is not good enough?

The code is wrong, so a warning would be good. G++ isn't smart enough to "see through" the call to `std::move`.  It's valid to pass an uninitialized variable by reference to a function (that function might initialize the variable) so calling `std::move` itself doesn't trigger a warning. Because `q` gets assigned a value, it appears to be initialized to the compiler.

If I turn on optimization so that G++ inlines the call to `std::move` then I get an error from G++ 4.7:

```
f.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
f.cc:6:9: warning: ‘p’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
```

This is because the call to `std::move` is no longer "opaque" to the compiler, when it analyses the inlined code it can see that `p` never gets assigned a value.  The compiler still isn't smart enough to see that `q` never gets a *good* value, the cast inside `std::move` probably confuses the compiler.

> 2- The next code should throw a warning?

No. `std::move` doesn't alter fundamental types such as pointers, so the value of `p` will not be changed.  The standard library says that objects are left in a "valid but unspecified" state after being moved from, because the standard doesn't generally define the exact behaviour of a move constructor or move assignment operator, but for fundamental types such as `int` and `char*` there is no move constructor. `std::move(p)` just casts the object to an rvalue, it doesn't alter it, and initializing `q` with the value doesn't alter it either - it just copies the value.

> 3- Other tools/compilers can check these errors?

Clang and ICC fail to warn about the first example even with optimization on.

Note that although warnings are very useful, compilers are not perfect and it is impossible to warn about all unsafe code.  You should not be totally surprised when unsafe code doesn't get a warning (maybe open a bug report for the compiler to request it be improved) -- it doesn't mean the code is OK.  Absence of warnings does not imply absence of bugs.

Comment: But in this case is a "rvalue reference", in what situation would you pass an uninitialized value? (For avoid calling a ctor when you know that pass a uninitialized is ok?)

Comment: No, you cannot "avoid calling a constructor" for an object with a constructor. You might do `int val; init(val);` to give `val` a value. The compiler assumes after a call to a function that might modify the object it might have a good value. Not making that assumption would give false warnings in correct code. Also, in this case you do not pass an rvalue reference to `std::move`, you pass an lvalue. The _return_ is an rvalue, not the argument.

Answer (score 0):

The move constructor of a pointer is trivial, which means it is the same as its copy constructor: copying the value. So as far as C++11 is concerned, this will copy pointers around. In your first case, it's copying uninitialized pointers around.

Now, if those were `std::unique_ptr` objects, it would not be correct code. But there's no reason to expect the compiler to warn about it, as there's no way for the compiler to be *certain* that a moved-from object cannot have `operator*` called on it.

In general, the standard library states that objects which have been moved-from are left in a valid but undefined state. For example, this is perfectly legal:

```
std::vector<int> src = ...;
std::vector<int> dest = std::move(src);
src.assign(...);
```

`std::unique_ptr` is different in that it specifies exactly what state the moved-from object is left it. But the compiler cannot assume that for any type. It can't assume that an object is left in an invalid state where any particular function call *must* fail.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Fair enough.